# Ubuntu Server 16.04.2

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning

Ok, call me newbie or whatever, here is my issue.

I've got my server running Ubuntu 16.04.2 server edition. Install ran smooth and I ran `fdisk /dev/sdb` to create `sdb1` partition on 2nd hdd. It is formatted now and using console how do I switch to it to create working directories? Simple most likely just forgot how to do it. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Did you `mount` it?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you already :

1. created partition in your `sdb` disk (you spoke about `/dev/sdb1`)
2. created filesystem (you said you have formatted).
   In case I'm wrong, do :

   ```
   mkfs -t filetype /dev/sdb1
   ```

   where *filetype* = ext3, ext2, etc4, etc.

Then you have to **mount** your device to be able to write, create directories, ...

```
mount -t filetype /dev/sdb1 /my/mount/directory
```

where:

- -t filetype: the filetype you have formatted your /dev/sdb1
- /my/mount/directory: an empty and existing directory (eg. in your system disk, I guess /dev/sdaX).